# Collection view selection like photo library

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a UIActionSheet that can display to the user, "Choose Existing Photo" and "Take Photo"

They work just fine. However, instead of choosing an existing photo from the user's library, I want to have them select a premade icon set that I will provide in a UICollectionViewController.

When doing the camera roll, it's as easy as using the line

```
mediaPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

where mediaPicker is a UIImagePickerController.

I'm sure what I am trying to do is close to the same lines. I have a UICollectionViewController with the icons displayed there, and I want the user to choose one of those so, the exact same functionality of the choosing from photo library.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to customize your own UIImagePickerController.

Some people created classes for that.

You can find one example [here](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) and another [here](https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController).